# "... in Introduction" vs "... in the introduction"

Tags: capitalization

I work on a thesis, with several chapters.

Now, Chapter 1 is called *Introduction*. When I want to say "ABC is defined in Chapter 1", I feel I can avoid using "Chapter 1" and use "Introduction".

However, I'm not sure which is correct:

1. "in the introduction" (referring to the general concept of introductions);
2. "in Introduction" (referring to Chapter 1 by its name);
3. neither, both, or something completely different.

Comment: It is only me, or has somebody down-voted the question and all the answers to it, without leaving any comment explaining the reasons? This seems very rude to me.

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer

> in the introduction

if that chapter ***is*** the introduction, or otherwise I would use

> in "Introduction"

For me,

> in Introduction

feels like broken English.